# Launching Terminal runs google-cloud-sdk script automatically?

Tags: node.js, bash, macos, terminal, google-cloud-sdk

I installed Google Cloud SDK a while back and I can't seem to stop this function from running every time I open my terminal.

`-bash: /Users/***/Desktop/***/node/y/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/***/Desktop/***/node/y/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc: No such file or directory`

Any thoughts on how I could remove it completely?

I've already tried: `npm uninstall google-cloud-sdk -g`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after some extensive digging.

It appears the Google Cloud SDK adds lines to the `.bash_profile` file in your user directory. Commenting out the source lines solved the issue.